# Payoff of a Butterfly spread under risk neutral measure is always positive for any t<T

Tags: options, option-pricing, no-arbitrage-theory

In a situation where $$K_3-K_2=K_2-K_1=h>0$$ and $$K_1\le S_t\le K_3$$ where $$S_T=S_t.e^{[(r-\sigma^2/2)(T-t)+\sigma(W_T-W_t)]}$$ (i.e. Stock process follows GBM under the risk neutral measure).

I know the value of the call under the risk neutral measure is:
$$f(S_t)= e^{-r(T-t)}*E((S_T-K_1)^+-2(S_T-K_2)^++(S_T-K_3)^+|\mathcal{F_t})$$
How do we know that the value of the payoff of the butterfly spread using calls is positive for any t<T.

Comment: It is based on the convexity of the call option payoff.

Comment: Can you elaborate or prove it?

Comment: What do you mean with "payoff ... for any t<T"? The payoff happens exactly at $T$, no? Do you mean *value* instead of *payoff*, by any chance?

Comment: Vandalizing questions is not allowed, edit rolled back

Answer (score 4):

Note that
\begin{align*}
K_2 = \frac{K_1+K_3}{2}.
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
&\ \max(S_T-K_1, \, 0) + \max(S_T-K_3, \, 0) \\
=&\ \max\big(S_T-K_1 + \max(S_T-K_3, \, 0), \, \max(S_T-K_3, \, 0)\big)\\
=&\ \max\big(\max(S_T-K_3 + S_T-K_1, \, S_T-K_1), \, \max(S_T-K_3, \, 0)\big)\\
=&\ \max\big(2S_T-(K_1+K_3), S_T-K_1, S_T-K_3, 0\big)\\
\ge&\ \max\big(2S_T-(K_1+K_3), 0\big)\\
=&\ 2\max(S_T-K_2, \, 0).
\end{align*}

Comment: Doesn't strictly positive imply that it is always >

Comment: Also how is this valid for every $$S_t$$ since $$S_T$$ is also variate on $$r, t and \sigma$$

Comment: The above derivation is model-free.